# tkinter asksaveasfilename doesn't work with more than 1 dot in file extension

Tags: linux, python-3.x, tkinter

If I use more than 1 dot in `filetypes` for `asksaveasfilename` it returns the name without any file types.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
file_name = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(
            filetypes= [("two dots", ".zz.zz"), ("one dot", ".zz") ])
print(file_name)
```

**Example:**

- Choosing `"two dots"` extension here, if I enter `hello` in the file name box, it returns `hello` as the name, not `hello.zz.zz`
- Choosing `"one dot"` extension here, if I enter `hello` in the file name box, it correctly returns `hello.zz`.

Is there an obvious reason for this? Is this a bug?

To be clear I'm not asking for workarounds... because that's a very easy thing to do here. I'm just asking why this happens.

---

I already experimented with `defaultextension`. Whatever I put there it will completely take over `filetypes`. What I mean is, it will rewrite whatever file type I choose. For example `defaultextension = ".x"` will return `.x` format if I choose either `.zz` or `.zz.zz` format, unless I write out the extension myself which eliminates the whole point of choosing file type from a menu. BTW I'm on Linux (Mint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't specific to having two dots, the problem is that you have a "non word character" after the dot. For example, you will see the same behavior if you use the pattern ".zz@" or ".#hash"

The filter is a mechanism for searching, not necessarily for setting the extension. Maybe it should be for setting the extension, but it's not. The dialog is designed for you to supply a default extension. If you don't, the behavior is platform specific. The canonical documentation for the `defaultextension` option says this (emphasis added):

> Specifies a string that will be appended to the filename if the user enters a filename without an extension. The default value is the empty string, which means no extension will be appended to the filename in any case. This option is ignored on Mac OS X, which does not require extensions to filenames, and *the UNIX implementation guesses reasonable values for this from the -filetypes option when this is not supplied.*

Unfortunately, this "guess" doesn't handle the case where there are non-word characters after the first dot. It's really as simple as that. Tkinter (or more correctly, the underlying tk library) will only use the pattern if it matches a dot followed by letters, numbers, or underscores.

Comment: Another answer that one can't find easily anywhere! Thanks for the knowledge Bryan.

Answer (score 0):

For questions involving the file system, please include OS, as that affects details.  On Windows 10, I do not get the either extension added.  Perhaps you are using Linux.  For Mac, you should add the Mac file type.  See [tk doc](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/getOpenFile.htm).

You omitted the 'defaultextension' argument.  A value of '' means 'add the extention.  On Mac, '' is not allowed and one must pick something non-empty as the default.  The following works for me to add either extension.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
file_name = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(
            filetypes= (("two dots", ".zz.zz"), ("one dot", ".zz")),
            defaultextension='')
print(file_name)
```

Please note that your single line was too little.  See [MCVE help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for that mcve reminder... I edited the question with some more detail. and added Linux tag